# Tailwind classes working inconsistently, why?

Tags: html, tailwind-css, margin, font-size, space

This might be an obvious solution, but I just don't get this inconsistent behavior from Tailwind.

I'm doing a website layout, and when I use some values for utilities like margin, space between or font size, it works fine, but then I try a different value and the class doesn't have any effect. For example, when I use mb-32 here, fine:

```
<div class="flex flex-col mb-32 space-y-12 md:w-1/2 md:mt-0">

            <h2 class="max-w-md text-3xl font-bold text-center md:text-5xl
            md:text-left">What's different about Manage?</h2>
            <p class="max-w-sm text-center text-darkGrayishBlue md:text-left">
                Manage provides all the functionality your team needs, without the
                complexity. Our software is tailor-made for modern digital product
                teams.
            </p>

</div>
```

[image]

I want the space to be a little shorter, so I use 28, 24 or 20, and none of them work:

[image]

I'm using Live Server btw, might have something to do, as some things I was trying yesterday that didn't work are working now.

Comment: Note that Tailwind will strip all css that isn't used at compile time (to limit the final bundle size). So Live Server may simply not have access to the classes because they do not occur anywhere in your (original) code. Hard to say if this is the case for you though, all depends on your setup.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, makes a lot of sense. Tested my code in Tailwind Play and classes are working fine.